# Converting string to list in newType

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a new data type called `BigNumber` which consists of a list of its digits. But when I try to create a function that receives a String and converts it to a `BigNumber` I always get an error.

```
newtype BigNumber = Digits [Char]

scanner :: String -> BigNumber
scanner a = id a
```

I have tried using the `id` function and `map` function but nothing works.

I always get the error

> ```
> Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘BigNumber’
>   Expected type: BigNumber
>     Actual type: String
> • In the expression: id a
>   In an equation for ‘scanner’: scanner a = id atypecheck(-Wdeferred-type-errors)
> ```

Comment: your data type definition suggest that `BigNumber` is just `Digits inputString` where `inputString` is the `String` that is given to the function as argument.

Comment: `newtype BigNumber = Digits [Char]` brings in scope the constructor `Digits :: [Char] -> BigNumber`, so I guess you want `scanner = Digits`. (Note that `String` and `[Char]` are exactly the same type)

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the fact that the "scanner" function expects a BigNumber type and a String type is being passed.

This code should work:

```
newtype BigNumber = Digits [Char]
scanner :: String -> BigNumber
scanner = Digits
```